# Interface vs Abstract class in Builder design pattern

Tags: typescript, design-patterns, interface, abstract-class, builder

In the context of the builder pattern, What is the most correct way to make the builder template?

With the interface is no able to specify the access permissions (public, protected and private), that means there may be a mismatch in the classes that implement it.

On the other hand, I think it is unnecessary to use an abstract class when all methods are going to be overwritten.

Here´re the exmaples:

Interface

```
// Builder
interface PizzaBuilder {
    pizza: Pizza;
    resert(): void;

    setTomamto(): this;
    setParmesano(): this;
    setPepper(): this;

    build(): Pizza;
}
```

Abstract class

```
// Builder
abstract class PizzaBuilder {
    protected pizza: Pizza = new Pizza
  
    protected abstract reset(): void;
    public abstract setTomamto(): this;
    public abstract setParmesano(): this;
    public abstract setPepper(): this;

    public abstract build(): Pizza;
}
```

Comment: To be frank, I don't see the need for a builder pattern in your example. Even more so, for an abstract builder.

Comment: An `interface`s methods are implicitly public. There cannot be a mismatch.

Comment: @Lesiak It is clearly just an example program for learning the builder pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have defined the abstract type makes them both equal in that they are just representing a contract for the implementor. Both versions enable polymorphism.

Usually you would use an abstract base class if all subclasses will share the same behavior. In this case the abstract base class can provide the related implementation.
Additionally, an abstract class allows to define internal (i.e. `protected`) members, whereas interface members must always be implemented as ´public`.

Let's assume we have two different types of ingredients: those from conventional agriculture and those cultivated using organic agriculture. This gives us two builders `ConventionFoodPizzaBulder` and `OrganicFoodPizzaBuilder`.
Now all builders could share the same logic to reset the build process and the same `build()` implementation too. In this case a common abstract base class that implements the reusable reset functionality makes perfect sense (because an interface would force each builder to implement the same functionality on its own --> duplicate code).

```java
abstract class PizzaBuilder {

  // Ensure the Pizza is not accessible outside this builder instance
  private Pizza pizza;

  // Internal implementation. When using interfaces, 
  // this method would have to be implemented explicitly by each implementation.
  protected void addToPizza(Topping pizzaTopping) {
    this.pizza.add(pizzaTopping);
  }

  public abstract PizzaBuilder addCheese();
  public abstract PizzaBuilder addTomatoes(int count);

  // Shared implementation. When using interfaces, 
  // this method would have to be implemented explicitly by each implementation.
  public Pizza build {
    return this.pizza;
  }
}
```

```java
class OrganicFoodPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {

  @Override
  public PizzaBuilder addCheese() {
    OrganicCheese cheese = new OrganicCheese();
    addToPizza(cheese);
  }

  @Override
  public PizzaBuilder addTomatoes(int count) {
    for (int tomatoeCount = 0; tomatoeCount < count; tomatoeCount++) {
      OrganicTomatoe tomatoe = new OrganicTomatoe();
      addToPizza(tomatoe);
    }
  }
}
```

```java
class ConventionalFoodPizzaBuilder extends PizzaBuilder {

  @Override
  public PizzaBuilder addCheese() {
    Cheese cheese = new Cheese();
    addToPizza(cheese);
  }

  @Override
  public PizzaBuilder addTomatoes(int count) {
    for (int tomatoeCount = 0; tomatoeCount < count; tomatoeCount++) {
      Tomatoe tomatoe = new Tomatoe();
      addToPizza(tomatoe);
    }
  }
}
```